# Can XCEED PropertyGrid accept structs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I can use Xceeds `PropertyGrid` control to correctly display all the relevant information for a `class` by binding the class object to `SelectedObject`.

However, this is not showing anything (no properties) when bind `SelectedObject` to a `struct`. The PropertyGrid binding is working as I see the name of the struct (ABFFileHeader) at the top (see image). Any ideas what is going on?

[image]

The struct looks like this:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct ABFFileHeader
        {
            // GROUP #1 - File ID and size information
            public float fFileVersionNumber;
            public short nOperationMode;            //y
            /// <summary>
            /// The total number of samples (not Duration)
            /// </summary>
            public int lActualAcqLength;
            public short nNumPointsIgnored;
            public int lActualEpisodes;
            public uint uFileStartDate;         // YYYYMMDD         //y
            public uint uFileStartTimeMS;           //y
            public int lStopwatchTime;
            public float fHeaderVersionNumber;
            public short nFileType;         //y

            // GROUP #2 - File Structure
            public int lDataSectionPtr;
            public int lTagSectionPtr;
            public int lNumTagEntries;
            public int lScopeConfigPtr;
            public int lNumScopes;
            public int lDeltaArrayPtr;
            public int lNumDeltas;
            public int lVoiceTagPtr;
            public int lVoiceTagEntries;
            public int lSynchArrayPtr;
            public int lSynchArraySize;
            public short nDataFormat;
            public short nSimultaneousScan;
            public int lStatisticsConfigPtr;
            public int lAnnotationSectionPtr;
            public int lNumAnnotations;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = Constants.ABF_DACCOUNT)]
            public int[] lDACFilePtr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I4, SizeConst = Constants.ABF_DACCOUNT)]
            public int[] lDACFileNumEpisodes;

            // GROUP #3 - Trial hierarchy information
            public short nADCNumChannels;
            public float fADCSequenceInterval;
            public uint uFileCompressionRatio;
            public sbyte bEnableFileCompression;                        //   bool %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            public float fSynchTimeUnit;
```

Comment: Probably because it's looking for actual properties rather than fields. What does your struct look like?

Comment: That makes sense. This should be a fairly simple change to implement by Xceed? I'm just asking before I suggest they implement.

Comment: It's not really them, you see Bindings in WPF work against properties, full stop. They will never work against fields. XCeed most likely reflect over your object looking for properties and generate UI and Bindings dynamically. Even if they reflected over fields as well the Bindings (framework code) still won't work.